Movie with murderer in apartment building playing loud music?
I am looking for the following movie. Maybe some of you saw it.
There was a guy who moved into an apartment building. One night there was loud music from another apartment, so he dialled the number of that apartment to complain. While doing so he lied and said that he was from a different apartment in the same building. Next morning they find the person he impersonated murdered.
I remember one conversation between the guy (A) and his best friend (B) after the murder happened:

A: Last night an idiot was playing loud music.
  B: Yes they are crazy in this city.
  A: Then I called him to stop it and gave a wrong door number when he asked who I was.
  B: That's normal. Everybody is lying around this city.
  A: Yes but it's not normal that the person from that apartment got murdered the same night.

Next the guy climbs to the supposed murderer's apartment through the balcony (if I remember correctly). There he finds a sound proof room and is puzzled.
The movie is probably from 1985 - 2000 and from the USA.

This description rings a bell, but I can't place it. I've surely seen that movie before. Doesn't the following happen as well in this scene? The murderer records himself talking as if on the phone. He places the recording near his phone, and at a certain time it is triggered to play while automatically making a phone call, while he is out murdering that other guy. The fake phone call is his alibi.

I don't think so. The murderer is called by the guy and is actualy talking to him. It's not the murderer calling someone else.

This is probably too obvious and doesn't quite fit but can we eliminate Driller Killer? That's about a guy who goes nuts because a punk band is rehearsing next door.

Do you mean this movie? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079082/

Yes, I meant that one Jenny, It's too early for 1985 but it was the loud music and murder combo that made me think of it.

I was just asking, because the description at imdb doesn't really match yours. Nevertheless, this is not the movie I am looking for. But thanks anyway.

The Courtyard (1995) 

Architect Jonathan moves into an LA courtyard apartment complex, then one of his neighbors is murdered by mistake.. Jonathan was the intended victim.

From reelfilm.com review:

McCarthy stars as a successful architect who's just moved into a Melrose Place-esque apartment building in Los Angeles. One night, he hears some strange noises coming from a nearby apartment, and walks to the front of the building and calls said apartment on the intercom (why he didn't just knock on their door is beyond me). Anyway, he tells the mysterious man who picks up that he's in the apartment across from his (a lie) and soon finds out that the actual inhabitant of that apartment has been murdered.







Trailer 



It could be The Upstairs Neighbour (1994)

Pulp novelist Eric lives in a bad neighborhood, and the guy upstairs annoys him with his noise. Gradually this escalates to pranksters phone calls and wire tapping which ticks off Eric's already unstable, nervous and paranoid personality.

I couldn't find more explanation about this film.




Thanks, but this is not the movie. I am sure. The one I am looking for had a higher budget. The neighbor was not upstairs and didn't do pagan rituals.
